# How should I use pip to install pyreverse on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: python, 15.04, pip

When I attempt to install pyreverse, I get the following pip message:

```
>sudo pip install pyreverse
Collecting pyreverse
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyreverse (from versions: )
  Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external pyreverse to allow).
No matching distribution found for pyreverse
```

I have no idea of how to address this and would welcome guidance.

Answer (score 2):

From the [`pyreverse` PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreverse/0.5.1):

> Pyreverse has now been integrated to pylint

So you most likely need to install that:

```
sudo pip install pylint
```

And the`pyreserve` command should be available.